# What's the mean of "?ac_id=2" in url?

Tags: url

For example there is a url `http://***.***.***.**/srun_portal_pc_us.php?ac_id=2&`, what is the mean of "?ac_id=2" in this url?

Answer (score 1):

This is a query string. The query string consists of one or more pairs of parameter names and values.

The PHP script will receive the query string and reformats into an array called `$_GET`. The $_GET array will have one element for each parameter in your query string.

In your case, since the value `2` was associated with the parameter `ac_id`, your PHP script would then be able to access the array element `$_GET['ac_id']` and retrieve the value `2`.

The parameter name `ac_id` could named anything you want as long as your URL and PHP script both use the same name.

If you want more than one value passed to your PHP script you must separate each parameter/value pair with an ampersand (&):

```
myscript.php?ac_id=2&first_name=Fred&last_name=Flintstone
```

Of course you need to modify the PHP script to handle the additional parameters.

In your example above you end the URL with an ampersand(&). The URL should not end with an ampersand.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning, this is referred to as a querystring parameter.

Comment: @Nate Thank you, I have reworked my answer.